# Android Google Maps circle change radius smoothly

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry

I want to control to circle by progress bar. But Google Maps API `setRadius` is not smoothly changing.

How to change circle radius smoothly?

This is my source code.

```
private Circle circle;
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().strokeWidth(0.0f)
            .center(34.1234233, 127.2312423)
            .fillColor(getResource().getColor(blue))
            .radius(0));
}

radiusSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        circle.setRadius(progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is seekBar having only 100 value (which are int) whereas circle radius is a double, instead of setRadius you should create an animation that update radius value "smoothly". Sadly i don't think GoogleMap circle have premade smooth update on circle radius.

Comment: What do you mean by "not smoothly changing"? Can you post screenshots of what you got?

Comment: Lary Ciminera : I try to double values in seekbar using max value * 10000. and convert double. but it's not a smooth..

Comment: abielita : umm... smooth isn't checking by screenshots......       umm..... if i change seekbar so it change to circle radius.. in this time circle is blinked