# Android google maps change circle radius smoothly

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map where I need to draw circle. Problem is that circle should be resizable (for example I have an `seekbar` and based on `seekbar` values I should see how my circle size (radius) is changing). I know how to draw a circle but I can't imagine how to make circle dynamically resizable. Is it possible?

EDIT here how I add circle to my map

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(latLng)
                .radius(100)
                .strokeWidth(0)
                .fillColor(0x66aaaFFF));
    }
```

as you can see I set radius to 100 each time when i click on map. However radius should change and circle should be drawn smoothly based on seekbar values

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447464/android-google-map-circle-change-redius-smoothly

Comment: well I don't find that answer. However it doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can make it dinamycally resizable changing the circle radius using the `setRadius` method on the `onProgressChanged` of the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`:

```
private Circle circle;

circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(52, 5))
    .fillColor(Color.RED)
    .radius(100));

AppCompatSeekBar progress = (AppCompatSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
progress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        circle.setRadius(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
    }
});
```

However there is a related unresolved known Google Maps bug ([Issue 5707: Bug: Circle filling flickers on fast circle radius and center update](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5707)) causing filling flickering.

**UPDATE:**

The issue 5707 has been [solved on October 24, 2016](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases)

Comment: Thanks for the answer sadly this is not the solution for me because of the flickering. Maybe there is an alternative way to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately using map `Circle`s it's not possible because of the bug I mention. You could draw a circle on a `View` over the map and draw and update your circles there, but the sinchronization between your `View` and the map will be very tricky (zooming, rotating and tilting the map will force you to manually update your `View`). I think that the best option is to wait for the bug to be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sadly this bug is 3 years old :/