# Android studio get last known location for maps and using a spinner to set circle radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-spinner

I am creating an app with a google maps and a circle radius centered on the user’s location. I want the user to choose the desired radius of the circle with a spinner (1-10 km radius). But when I use the value from my spinner the radius circle doesn't appear.

For the location I can get the blue dot showing my appearance by: map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); and I can manually enter a location for map to zoom into. But when I try to zoom into and set center of circle on the device location I get a nullpointerexception error. Below is my code for the location and the toast is just for me to see that I get the actual location.

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        return;
    }
    Task<Location> task = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                currentLocation = location;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Current Position " + currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Just to make sure we have a value
                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Then I use userPosition for map to zoom into and set center of circle

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    LatLng userPosition = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());

    mGoogleMap = map;
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userPosition, 10f));

    map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(userPosition)
            .radius(mapRadius)
            .strokeColor(0x330073FF)
            .fillColor(0x330073FF)
            .strokeWidth(2));

    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

But here I get the error on the line userPosition:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.test.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:362).

I got the code from a tutorial and it seems to work for them and tried many different tutorials as well with slightly different code so not sure what I do wrong. I have tried searching and know others had similar problems but still haven't gotten it to work.

As for the radius, it works fine when I set a manual location and write It works well if I write the radius myself in meters. But if I try to use my spinner and the mapRadius value, the radius circle doesn’t show up at all when I run the emulator. This is the code that is in onCreate

```
spinnerRadius = findViewById(R.id.spinner_radius);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_radius_option, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerRadius.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinnerRadius.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mapRadiusInput = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            mapRadius = Double.parseDouble(mapRadiusInput)*1000; //converting to meters
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+mapRadius, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I am a beginner when it comes to programming and android and I spent quite a bit on time on these two problem and it wouldn’t surprise me if it is easy to solve. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to update the circle in the `onItemSelected` - see `setRadius` on the `Circle` object returned from `addCircle`, just setting the `mapRadius` doesn't update the circle. As far as the null pointer - the code posted looks fine - you are getting the map after getting a location update so the problem may be elsewhere.  So the selection is in 1/1000th meters units?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The selection is in km but is converted to meters. I get the problem with the radius now, but I am not really sure how to fix it. Could you elaborate your suggestion or show me a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the circle, save the return value (`Circle`) in a field variable, `Circle myCircle`.

Then in the `onItemSelected` update the circle radius with the value (in meters).

So, first declare the variable as a class field variable (for scope visibility later).  I'm assuming this is all in one class - if not you'll need to make this variable accessible to the `onItemSelected` callback instance.

```
private Circle myCircle;
```

Then when adding the circle, save it:

```
myCircle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
        .center(userPosition)
        .radius(mapRadius)
        .strokeColor(0x330073FF)
        .fillColor(0x330073FF)
        .strokeWidth(2));
```

And in your `onItemSelected`, update the circle (in meters)

```
myCircle.setRadius(mapRadius);
```

Here's another example showing same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38454501/2711811

And API doc: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#setRadius(double)

The key is to save the `Circle` when it's created.  And as you can see from the API, with the `Circle` reference there are other setters which can be used.

Comment: Great description, as a beginner it really helps. Thank you so much for your help.